# Why does it contain "Using where"?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `usr_block_phone` (
    `usr_block_phone_uid` BIGINT (20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `usr_uid` INT (10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `block_phone` VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    `status` INT (4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`usr_block_phone_uid`),
    KEY `block_phone` (`block_phone`),
    KEY `usr_uid_block_phone` (`usr_uid`, `block_phone`) USING BTREE,
    KEY `usr_uid` (`usr_uid`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
```

And This is my SQL

```
SELECT
    ubp.usr_block_phone_uid
FROM
    usr_block_phone ubp
WHERE
    ubp.usr_uid = 19
AND ubp.block_phone = '80000000001'
```

By the way, when I ran "EXPLAIN", I got the result as following.

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                           | key                 | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ubp   | ref  | block_phone,usr_uid_block_phone,usr_uid | usr_uid_block_phone | 66      | const,const |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Why is index `usr_uid_block_phone` not working?
I want to use  `using index` only.

This table has 20000 rows now.

Comment: How many rows in that table?

Comment: 1 row.  An index is not needed.

Comment: So fill it with a million rows and check. Performance optimisation does not scale: you must check every case specifically.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Why not needed? Later, this table will have to use in sub query.

Comment: @Star_Man "Later" --- `EXPLAIN` shows the current execution plan for your current data and your current query. It cannot predict the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index is actually used, see the `key` column. At the moment the query looks good and the execution plan is good as well.

Fill it with at least a hundred for it to be used (and ensure you still use a predicate that filters just one row).

And a general advice: it's near to impossible to predict how optimiser would behave in a particular situation unless you're a mysql dbms developer yourself. So it's always better to try on a dataset that is as close (in terms of size and quality of data) to your production as possible.

Comment: I inserted 20000 rows, and I try it. But I get the equal result only.

Comment: "But I get the equal result only" --- what does it mean?

Comment: The result of 'explain' contains "using where" still, although this table has 20000 rows.

Comment: @Star_Man so? Any problem with it?

Comment: | id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                           | key                 | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ubp   | ref  | block_phone,usr_uid_block_phone,usr_uid | usr_uid_block_phone | 66      | const,const |    1 | Using where; Using index |

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156439/discussion-between-star-man-and-zerkms).

Answer (score 1):

Both columns that are used in the `WHERE` clause (`usr_uid` and `block_phone`) are present in the `usr_uid_block_phone` index and this makes it a possible key to be used to process the query. Even more, it is **the** index selected but because of the small number of rows in the table, MySQL decides that is faster to not use an index.

The reason is in the expressions present in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
    ubp.usr_block_phone_uid
```

Because the column `usr_block_phone_uid` is not present in the selected index, in order to process the query MySQL needs to read both the index (to determine what rows match the `WHERE` conditions) **and** the table data (to get the value of column `usr_block_phone_uid` of those rows).

It is faster to read only the table data and use the `WHERE` conditions to find the matching rows and get their `usr_block_phone_uid` column. It needs to read data from storage from one place. It needs to read the same data **and** the index data if it uses an index.

The situation (and the report of `EXPLAIN`) changes when the table grows. At some point, reading information from the index (and using it to filter out rows) is compensated by the large number of rows that are filtered out (i.e. their data is not read from the storage).

The exact point when this happens is not fixed. It depends a lot of the structure of your table and how the values in the table are spread out. Even when the table is large, MySQL can decide to ignore the index in order to read less information from the storage medium. For example, if a large percentage (let's say 90%) of the table rows match the `WHERE` condition, it is more efficient to read all the table data (and ignore the index) than to read 90% of table data and 90% of the index.

*90% in the previous paragraph is a figure I made up for explanation purposes. I don't know how MySQL decides that it's better to ignore the index.*

Comment: Thank you, But this table have 20000 rows now.

Comment: @Star_Man ... and it uses the index.